# Вывести среднее значение численных значений свойств объекта

Tags: javascript

Почему не выводит среднее значение???

```js
'use strict';

let users = {
    'Alex': 32,
    'Peter': 18,
    'Mary': 20,
    averageAge: function(){
        let result = 1;
        for (let key in this){
            result *= this[key];
            
        }
        return result / 3;
    }
    
}
users.averageAge()
console.log(users.averageAge())
```

Comment: очевидно потому что функция это не число. Плюс среднее считается неправильно. если это среднее арифметическое - надо было складывать, а не умножать, если среднее геометрическое, надо было извлекать корень а не делить.

Comment: Ну так то this[key] возвращает функцию. А key это строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

let users = {
  'Alex': 32,
  'Peter': 18,
  'Mary': 20,
}
Object.defineProperty(users, 'averageAge', {
  enumerable: false,
  get() {
    let r = 0
    let k = Object.keys(this)
    //k.forEach(k => r += this[k])
    //--
    for(let key in this){
      r += this[key]
    }
    //--
    return r / k.length
  }
})

console.log(users.averageAge)
```

а вот ваш код

```js
'use strict';

let users = {
  'Alex': 32,
  'Peter': 18,
  'Mary': 20,
  averageAge() {
    for (let key in this) {
      console.log(this[key])
    }
  }
}
users.averageAge()
```

Comment: Понял ошибку. Глупая ошибка. По-моему, вот так лучше всего - https://alexseveneight78.github.io/playground/#-LLDtKaBf0QLzc-sCNXY

Comment: да хоть так :) `let averageAge = obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / Object.keys(obj).length;
alert(averageAge(users))`  но в вашем примере, я бы передавал `users` как параметр `function age(obj){};console.log(age(users))`